# docker-compose build process that pulls from two distinct GitHub private repositories

Tags: github, docker-compose, ssh

I have a docker-compose file with one dockerfile that I use to build multiple containers. Originally, there was one GitHub private key associated with multiple repos that was used as part of the build process to download the necessary code from GitHub into one of the containers. That key was unfortunately checked into the repository.

To fix that security hole I'm trying to rework the build process by switching to deploy keys, one per repo. The challenge is that I have two separate private GitHub repositories that the build process has to pull from, and I can't figure out how to handle the authentication. At a high level, the first repo calls `pip install <second_repo>` as part of the build process, and I need to have that process authenticate to the second repo.

I have created two distinct GitHub deploy keys, one per repository. If I do the following, I can authenticate to the main private repo, but it fails on authentication to the second repo:

```
COPY conf/private_key_1 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
COPY conf/private_key_1.pub /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
COPY conf/private_key_2 /root/.ssh/private_key_2
COPY conf/private_key_2.pub /root/.ssh/private_key_2.pub
RUN <script that writes both public keys into /.ssh/authorized_keys>

RUN chmod 0600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub \
    /root/.ssh/private_key_2 /root/.ssh/private_key_2 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Is there a way to do this? Would implementing the second repo as a submodule be a better approach? Please help. Thank you!